# Weird behavior for infix functions regarding precedence

Tags: haskell, operator-precedence

I am using the `bool :: a -> a -> Bool -> a` function.
I wanted to use the infix version, because I though it more readable, but I noticed that:

```
(-1) `bool` 1 True
```

is an error

```
(-1) `bool` 1 $ True
```

works. Even

```
(-1) `bool` 1 (True)
```

doesn't work, which I thought was an equal alternative until now (i.e. using `$` versus wrapping in parentheses from this location till the end)

How can this even make a difference? In the first version there is only one single operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Infix operators bind loosely, applications bind tightly.

```
(-1) `bool` 1 True
-- means
(-1) `bool` (1 True)


(-1) `bool` 1 $ True
-- means
((-1) `bool` 1) $ True


(-1) `bool` 1 (True)
-- means
(-1) `bool` (1 (True))
```

You might want:

```
((-1) `bool` 1) True
```

Comment: I incur from this that infix operators with more than 2 arguments always need some special attention?

Comment: Nitpick: I think you mean "infer".

Comment: @hgiesel I believe functions with more than two arguments are usually applied in prefix notation, only.